# comparison of two arrays and removing duplicates

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi Here are my Two Arrays.
A[]={1,2,3,4,5}
B[]={3,4,5}

Expected Output:

C[]={1,2}

Can someone try to explain the solution in c++

Please find the code that i tried.We had some problem uploading the code.Please find the algorithm we tried

1) Taken Two Arrays A and B
2) Array A containing m elements and B contains n elements.m>n
3) Took the inputs for Array A and Array B from Standard Input
4) Comparing the elements in both the Arrays element wise using two for loop 
   where each element of array A compared with each element of Array B and if 
   not equal push the element into new array.

But we faced two problems here once in case the first element of Array A not equal to first element of B it will be taken as not a duplicate.But that element will be equal to the last element of array B in that case my code fails.

Next is that we are able to get the elements which are not duplicate from Array A into C but if want to get the elements which are not duplicated  from array B into C.Do we need to implement for loop again.?

Comment: post the code you have tried. This is not a code writing service. It so looks like a homework to me

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to explain the problem better to start. Are the arrays sorted?

Answer (score 0):

If you use std::vector, so can use std::find for find a element of B in A.

`for(int i = 0; i<B.size(); i++)
    std::find(A.begin() ,A.end(), B[i])`